# How do i make the buttons from the following code be all the same size and occupy the entire gridLayout?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have this grid layout which is part of an another grid layout, and contains 6 buttons.
It is next to a relative grid layout, if that makes any difference, thats why its width and height are set at 0dp.

How do I make them all the same size and make them fill the grid without using fixed values?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:columnCount="2"
            app:rowCount="3"
            >


             <Button
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="@string/pocetna_dugme_prijava_problema"
            style="@style/StartMenuButton"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_button_start_menu"
            android:id="@+id/btnPrijavaProblemaLink"/>

        <Button
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               
            android:text="@string/pocetna_dugme_prijava_ebill"
            style="@style/StartMenuButton"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_button_start_menu"
            android:id="@+id/btnPrijavaEracunLink"/>

        <Button
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              
         
            android:text="@string/pocetna_dugme_prijava_ukljucenje"
            style="@style/StartMenuButton"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_button_start_menu"
            android:id="@+id/btnUkljucenjeLink"/>

        <Button
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             
            
            android:text="@string/pocetna_dugme_prepaid_dopuna"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/prepaid10"
            style="@style/StartMenuButton"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_button_start_menu"
            android:id="@+id/btnPrepaidDopunaLink"/>
```

Comment: Change android:layout_width="wrap_content"  to fill_parent instead

Answer (score 0):

If you want the control to divide the screen space horizontally and vertically,you can use `LinearLayout` to achieve this, and set the `android:layout_weight="1"` property for the controls.

And to make the UI look better, you can also set `android:layout_margin` property.

You can refer to the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"    
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <Button
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
         <Button
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
         <Button
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="button4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change all your nested LinearLayouts to use ConstraintLayouts. Nested LinearLayouts inflate slowly, which was why ConstraintLayouts were created to replace them about 4-5 years ago. Android.Support.V7.Widgets were also dropped in favour of AndroidX controls at about the same time.